# Can Chef-server be used with a wildcard certificate?

Tags: ssl, chef-infra

I have been trying to add a wildcard certificate to my chef server and while browsing to the web UI Chrome is happy with the certifiate and I can browse the signing certificates, but Knife and chef-client both don't seem to care for it.  Even fetching and adding the cert into the trusted certs doesn't seem to satisfy them.

Before I purchase a fully named cert is there a tech reason that a wildcard doesn't work with chef-server <-> chef-client communications?

Thanks

Comment: I can only report for Chef Server 11 (nodes and clients running 12) that I never had a problem with our wildcard cert, deployed by [this cookbook](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/site-cheftypo3org/blob/master/attributes/default.rb). Not sure, how much has changed with Chef Server 12, the options still look the same.

Comment: Ah, sorry, this appeared in my list because of the other answer. Sorry for digging in the dirt..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell I had bad times with the trusted_cert directory (I did not dig to see why).

I always ended by adding my CA certs to the `embedded/ssl/cert/cacerts.pem` file.
what sounds strange is that if you use a wildcard cert trusted by a public CA you should not have ssl errors.

If you have an intermediate CA not know in the cacert.pem, add its certificate in it and it should be ok.

On last resort you may add the wildcard cert itself to this file.

Knowing the error given my `knife ssl check` may help understand why. I see no reason a wildcard cert would fail generally speaking.

Comment: I think I found out what it was.  The reverse DNS is pointed to a different host.  I find it strange that Chrome thinks it's fine.  I haven't fixed the reverse DNS yet because it's in amazon ec2's public record.  I created a self signed cert based on the ec2 name and it works fine for now.  I will be moving the chef server to my VPC soon and will have better control over the DNS and will test again then.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, wildcard certificate can be used for chef server.

Do not forget to add `root.crt` and `intermediate.crt` to your nginx:

```
cat server.crt intermediate.crt root.crt >> /var/opt/opscode/nginx/ca/FQDN.crt
```

And then:

```
Reconfigure the Chef server:
$ chef-server-ctl reconfigure
Restart the Nginx service to load the new key and certificate:
$ chef-server-ctl restart nginx
```

I used [this](https://docs.chef.io/server_security.html) article.

Comment: This is the real answer. Some CAs aren't present in embedded/ssl/certs/cacerts.pem and so for those providers, you need to serve the whole CA chain with your cert.